# Switch between databases in spring/ hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

In my project I use Spring and hibernate. I use MySql and use auto increment for Ids. But now I need to support multiple database types. (separate installations). Say, MySql, Oracle (11g), Postgresql, etc.

My current idea is to use uuid for primary keys since I can switch to any database without much worrying about database layer. But since  I have used Integer for auto_increment I have to modify my code base.

Is there a way to preserve Integer id? or shall I proceed with uuid ?

Current implementation

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer id;
```

Or this, (or any other solution)

```
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    @Column
    @Id
    private String id;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this.

Idea is to add annotation configuration and override it using xml.

```
XML metadata may be used as an alternative to these annotations, or to override or augment annotations
```

Here is a good tutorial for this,

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-replace-the-table-identifier-generator-with-either-sequence-or-identity-in-a-portable-way/